# Sending data between fragments without creating new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a fragment (WifiSetupFragment) that calls a DialogFragment, and that DialogFragment needs to pass a string back to the original fragment. I know to do this you have an interface in the activity that will send data to the original fragment like so, which I am already doing:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frag, WifiSetupFragment.newInstance(password));
transaction.commit();
```

So the first time I call WifiSetupFragment, I haven't created a DialogFragment yet because I haven't clicked on an item to open the dialog. My question is should I just call

```
WifiSetupFragment.newInstance(null)
```

and have a null check for the password string in my fragment? Because I don't have a password unless the DialogFragment is open, and it's not always open. If this made no sense, please tell me and I'll try to explain more clearly. I guess it just seems strange to me to have a parameter for a string that might only be sent to this fragment occasionally since the data isn't constantly being passed in.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on purpose of fragment and dialog? My understanding is that fragment reports a list of wifi networks. By clicking on one of them, dialog should be displayed for inserting password. By confirming, password is sent back to fragment and its UI is updated accordingly. Is it right?

Comment: Is there a reason why the dialogfragment cant use the interface to communicate directly with the fragment?

Comment: @thetonrifles yes, that's right.

Comment: @MidasLefko the stuff I was reading seemed to say that fragments shouldn't communicate directly with each other, only through the activity which is why I'm trying to do it that way. Also, I did try it directly and it wasn't working but that's probably an error on my part.

Comment: @googlygoogly2 Well, so you probably just need to have fragment receiving input password from dialog through a simple interface. You don't need to involve the activity.

Comment: @googlygoogly2 Look at reference [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to communicate between these Fragments through the Activity. What you can do instead:

1. Make your `WifiSetupFragment.newInstance()` accept no parameters.
2. Make `WifiSetupFragment` implement a new interface, let's call it `OnPasswordSuppliedListener`.
3. Once you create your `DialogFragment` instance, attach it to a `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.
4. Now inside of your `DialogFragment` subclass you can reference `WifiSetupFragment` by calling `getParentFragment()`.
5. Cast `getParentFragment()` to your interface and voila!

Note: I'm assuming you're using Fragments from the support library. Otherwise please be aware that nested Fragments feature was introduced in the API 17.

Comment: Good answer, using an event bus such as Otto could also be used.

Comment: this is what I ended up doing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog can define an interface allowing to send input password back to parent fragment / activity:

```
public class TestDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private TextView mPasswordView;
    private OnPasswordDefinedCallback mCallback;

    public static TestDialog newInstance() {
        TestDialog dialog = new TestDialog();
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflate layout for your dialog (it must include edit text for password)
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_test, null);
        // getting ui elements from layout
        mPasswordView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        // building dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    mCallback = (OnPasswordDefinedCallback) getTargetFragment();
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    throw new ClassCastException("must implement OnPasswordDefinedCallback");
                }
                if (mCallback != null) {
                    // send password back to parent
                    mCallback.doPasswordDefined(mPasswordView.getText().toString());
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }


    public interface OnPasswordDefinedCallback {

        void doPasswordDefined(String password);

    }

}
```

Then in `WifiSetupFragment` you can proceed as follows for opening `PasswordDialog`:

```
TestDialog dialog = TestDialog.newInstance();
dialog.setTargetFragment(WifiSetupFragment.this, 1);
dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```

`WifiSetupFragment` must of course implement interface `OnPasswordDefinedCallback`.

Comment: This can be bit problematic on configuration/orientation changes, since the callback reference won't be retained when FragmentManager recreates your fragments for you.

Comment: @MateuszHerych I edited answer for an eventual better management of configuration/orientation changes, using target fragment.